# how to cache channel aggregation feed that can be customizable for each user?

Tags: neo4j, redis, feed, channel

we already use Redis in our development stack and I prefer to use it but I know that neo4j has some great tools for it.
there are about 14 channels that publish contents every day.
there are about 1M users and every user can customize his (her) own feed to aggregate data of a combination of these channels

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the "[graphity model](http://www.rene-pickhardt.de/graphity-an-efficient-graph-model-for-retrieving-the-top-k-news-feeds-for-users-in-social-networks/)" is for you.